# Proof of Maschke’s theorem: Why is $\hat{p}$ again a projection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, proof-explanation

> **Question**: In the proof of Maschke’s theorem we construct for every subrepresentation $U \subseteq V$ a $G$-equivariant projection onto $U$.
>   How can we abstractly see that for any $k$-linear projection $p \colon V \to V$ onto $U$, the resulting $G$-equivariant map $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} (g.\!p) \colon V \to V$ must again be a projection onto $U$?

---

**Setup**:
Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field with $\operatorname{char} k \nmid |G|$.
Then for every representation $V$ of $G$ the map
$$
          V
  \to     V
  \quad   v
  \mapsto \hat{v}
  :=      \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g.\!v
$$
is a projection onto the subspace $V^G \subseteq V$ of $G$-invariants.
We will refer to this as the *projection onto invariants*.

This is famously used in (one of) the proofs of Maschke’s theorem:
Let $V$ be a representation of $G$ over $k$ and let $U \subseteq V$ be a subrepresentation.
Starting off with any $k$-linear projection $p \colon V \to V$ onto $U$, one can apply the projection onto invariants to the representation $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,V)$ to get a new map
$$
    \hat{p}
\in \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,V)^G
=   \operatorname{Hom}_G(V,V) \,.
$$
One can then check that this $G$-endomorphism $\hat{p}$ is again a projection onto $U$, e.g. by checking that $\operatorname{im} \hat{p} \subseteq U$ and that $\hat{p}(u) = u$ for every $u \in U$.

While the projection onto invariants nicely explains how to translate the $k$-linear projection $p$ into a $G$-endomorphism $V \to V$, I have not yet found an explanation for why $\hat{p}$ will again be a projection onto $U$.
(“Checking on elements” proves *that* it works, but doesn’t explain *why* it works.)

> How can we abstractly see that by applying the projection onto invariants to $p$, the resulting $G$-endomorphism $\hat{p}$ must again be a projection onto $U$?

---

This is what I tried/figured out so far:

- Suppose that $W \subseteq V$ is a $k$-linear subspace which is not a subrepresentation, and let $q \colon V \to V$ be a projection onto $W$.

  - Then $\hat{q} \colon V \to V$ doesn’t have image $W$ since $\hat{q}$ is $G$-equivariant and $\operatorname{im} \hat{q}$ is therefore a subrepresentation of $V$.
    But $\operatorname{im} \hat{q}$ is contained in the subrepresentation generated by $W$.
  - $\hat{q}$ is not necessarily a projection.
    (Example:
    Let $\mathbb{Z}/4$ acts on $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, let $W$ be the $x$-axis and $q$ the orthogonal projection.
    Then $\hat{q}(x) = x/2$ for every $x \in W$, so that $\hat{q}^2 \neq \hat{q}$.)

  So it seems pretty important for $U$ to be a subrepresentation of $V$.
- For every $G$-homomorphism $f \colon V \to W$ one has that $f(\hat{v}) = \widehat{f(v)}$.
  In fancy language we may regard $\widehat{(-)}$ as a natural transformation from the identity functor to the taking-invariants functor $(-)^G$.
  Since $\widehat{(-)}_V$ is a projection for every representation $V$, this generalizes to a natural decomposition $V = V^G \oplus V^{\text{non-triv}}$.
- Given $k$-linear maps $f \colon U \to V$, $g \colon V \to W$ the first point shows that it does not always hold that $\widehat{f \circ g} = \hat{f} \circ \hat{g}$ (otherwise $\hat{q}$ would again be a projection).
  But it follows from the second point that
  $$
    \widehat{\hat{f} \circ g}
  = \hat{f} \circ \hat{g}
  = \widehat{f \circ \hat{g}}
    $$
  since $\operatorname{Hom}_k(U,V) \to \operatorname{Hom}_k(U,W)$, $h \mapsto \hat{g} \circ h$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W) \to \operatorname{Hom}_k(U,W)$, $h \mapsto h \circ \hat{f}$ are $G$-homomorphisms (which holds because $\hat{g}$ and $\hat{f}$ are $G$-homomorphisms).
- One can use the projection onto invariants to give different, more abstract proofs of Maschke’s theorem (e.g. section 3.2 [here](https://amakelov.github.io/2016/02/13/Representation-theory-Reducibility.html), which uses the natural decomposition from the second point).
  But I have not yet found such an abstract proof which better explains the “classical” proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The range of $p$ is $G$--invariant if and only if  for all $g \in G$, $p g p = g p$.   Assume range of $p$ is $G$--invariant.  Write $\hat p$ more explictly as $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g p g^{-1}$.  A little computation based on the observation above shows $\hat p^2 = \hat p$.    I don't know if you would consider this as an explanation.

Comment: I am on my phone right now, but if you want a more detailed explanation of the proof, there is one in my representation  theory notes. If you google my name and add "pure" you should find my AU PURE page, which has a link to the notes.

Comment: I wrote an attempt at an answer based on the ideas I got from @TobiasKildetoft’s (very useful) notes.
This does not mean that I consider this question as answered yet;
this is in particular not meant as a discouragement for anybody else to provide their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach is based on section 5 of [Tobias Kildetoft’s notes](http://pure.au.dk/portal/en/persons/tobias-kildetoft(50a5bf8e-9302-4432-af72-ed80268ec9c1)/publications/introduction-to-the-representation-theory-of-finite-groups(7e767505-f2c8-44d1-8756-bb9e9f06afde).html) about the representation theory of finite groups.

1. Note that for every $g \in G$ the map $g.\!p = gpg^{-1}$ results from $p$ by conjugating with $g$.
   Since $p$ is a projection onto the linear subspace $U$ it follows that $g.\!p$ is a projection onto the conjugated linear subspace $g.\!U$.
2. Because $U$ is a subrepresentation we have that $g.\!U= U$.
   **Hence every summand $g.\!p$ is itself already a projection onto $U$.**
3. For every finite collection of projections $q_1, \dotsc, q_n$ on $U $, their average $\hat{q} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n q_i$ is again a projection onto $U$ (where we assume that that $\operatorname{char} k \nmid n$).
   This can be seen in at least the following two ways:

   a.  The conditions that $q(u) = u$ for every $u \in U$ and that $q(v) \in U$ for every $v \in V$ are both preserved by taking averages.

   b.  For every two projections $q_i, q_j$ onto $U$ we have that $q_i q_j = q_j$, so that
       \begin{align*}
           \hat{q}^2
         = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n q_i q_j
         = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n q_j
         = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n q_j
         = \hat{q}.
       \end{align*}

Note that this approach shows that *all* of the maps $V \to V$ appearing in the proof of Maschke’s theorem are already projections onto $U$.
So we never lose the property of “being a projection onto $U$” throughout the proof, resulting in $\hat{p}$ also being a projection onto $U$.

---

One can probably further enhance/abstract the above observations:
Note for example that 3.a. actually argues that the subset $A \subseteq \operatorname{Hom}_k(V,V)$ of projections onto $U$ is closed under affine combinations, and is therefore an affine subspace, and that 1. and 2. explain why $A$ is closed under the action of $G$.
As the process of averaging already makes sense in the affine subspace $A$ it follows that the average $\hat{p}$ lies again in $A$.
(So maybe we should look into affine actions?)